# How to keep two Youtube videos in sync?

Tags: java, android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I'm developing an app that allows users to watch a video on YouTube in sync.
When a user pauses a video, the video should be paused for everyone and when a video of some user is buffering, the others should be paused too (similar to https://www.watch2gether.com/). Is it possible to do this with youtube android api?

Answer (score 0):

Use socket, trigger a event when user pauses pass it all connected clients.